# Global typewriter tab stops every 1/2 inch

Tags: spacing, indentation

What is the best method, please, for setting up the equivalent of global (document-wide) typewriter tab stops every 1/2 inch?

I'm reluctant to set up a tabular definition `\begin{tabbing}` at the document begin / end, because that might affect single / double spacing, double-indent quotations, etc.

I've defined a keyword (`\tab`) to be equal to 1/2 inch, but that doesn't resolve the alignment issues.  I do not want an outline feature per se.  I just want global typewriter tab stops, if possible.

Begin paragraph here.

A.     Subparagraph.

(i.)     Sub-sub-paragraph

*      This is a new paragraph that needs to line up with the letter `A.`

Comment: There really is no best method to do that, it just isn't the way Tex works. You can probably force something but it will be painful and incompatible with most TeX structures. LaTeX is designed to work with nested lists, if (i.) was marked up as an `enumerate` list the following sentence would automatically revert to the margin before the list.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to this? Perhaps there is a missunderstanding we can get rid off?

Comment: Tab stops are engrained upon my soul.  I learned to type on a manual typewriter (ink ribbon and carbon paper); and worked in various clerical jobs for years before becoming a high volume litigation secretary (10 years); and am now a law firm of one.  I have used WordPerfect since about 1986 and  MicrosoftWord for the past 4 years.  In my opinion, the easiest method to quickly indent and align a variety of paragraphs / sub-paragraphs is with tab stops.  It is also a quick alternative to setting up tables, minipages, tabbing, etc.  Although I already have many snippets, tab stops are preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with [the `tabto` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabto-ltx):

[image]

## Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabto}
\TabPositions{0.5in,1.0in,1.5in,2.0in}

\begin{document}
Some text \tab Tab

Some more text \tab Tab

Some longer text \tab Tab

Text \tab Tab
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your suggestion looks very promising -- I will work with that package and report back.  The documentation states on the first line:  \tabto{<length>} moves the type­set­ting po­si­tion to <length> from the left mar­gin of the para­graph.  Thank you so very much!

Comment: Because I was already using \tab for my own user-defined 5 spaces, substituting the package tabto made my first test document work perfectly!  What an awesome help you have been -- thank you so much -- zero configuration -- just added a couple more tab stops for good luck.

Comment: Though I'm happy you're content with the answer, please do take the time to consider David Carlisle's comment; TeX is so much more than just an electric typewriter...